# Importing file of same file and function name in python

Tags: python, import

```
src
 |
  -- Country
     |
      -- test_file.py -> test_file(function)
  -- State
     |
      -- test_file.py -> i want to run this file
```

I have to run the test_file in State which is the present working directory. I have to import the function test_file from test_file in country.

Using the path

```
import sys
sys.path.append('../Country')
from test_file import *

print test_file()
```

When i run the file. It says role_name function not found.
It is not able to find the function.
But if i change the name of the file in Country from test_file to some other name, Its working fine.
I am thinking this problem has to do with some kind of ambiguousness.

I need to have the same name for both files.
Is there another way out for this problem?

Comment: from `..Country.test_file import role_name`…?!

Comment: Attempted relative import in non-package <-- gives this error. I dont have the luxury to run it in this format "python - m test_file.py"

Comment: The answers to this question might be helpfull:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/67631/how-to-import-a-module-given-the-full-path In the answers they show the use of importlib (python 3)/ imp (python 2).

Comment: `print dir()` and check the imported methods.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace `sys.path.append('../Country')` by `sys.path.insert(0, '../Country')`

Since you append your Country module at the end of the path, `test_file.py` in current working directory (State)  will take precedence. Inserting at the beginning of the path should solve that.
Also do not use `import *` but `import role_path`, this way the import directive will fail if the required object is not found, instead of silently continuing and letting errors trigger later.

But it would be a lot cleaner to just import your function this way, if Country is a proper module (with an `__init__.py` or not depending on the Python version):

```
from ..Country.test_file import role_path
```

Comment: this makes sense. I've faced a similar problem before! and sys.path.insert() came to rescue!

Comment: sys.path.insert() worked like a charm. Thank you, Guillaume!